# What happened to Andre?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, cloak-and-dagger

In the final episode of the second season of *Cloak and Dagger*, Tandy and Tyrone confront Andre in his world (the Dark Dimension, perhaps). They manage to catch him by surprise, and Tandy stabs him through the chest with a sword of light. They then touch him together and enter his mind, forcing him to hear his own melody and experience the despair that he makes others feel. Later, they leave somewhat abruptly and end up back in the physical realm, where they do not talk about it but seem convinced that the problem has been resolved.

Of course, by this point he is a spirit (a *loa*, as Voudon would see it), and his body is already dead, so it is not clear whether this would kill him the way it would an ordinary person. Further, at the end we see some people drawing his symbol on his gravestone, with the cloak and dagger symbol incorporated therein, suggesting that they are now worshipping him.

Finally, when the kids enter the Dark Dimension in *Runaways*, they see nightmarish images; further, Tandy says "the loa traps you in your own worst nightmares". Of course, Andre is not the only loa in the Dark Dimension (or at least who makes a habit of entering the Dark Dimension) who is capable of doing something along these lines—Papa Legba appeared to Mayhem as her dead, bloodied boyfriend, Baron Samedi put Tyrone in a video game, and Morgan has her own tricks. Still, despair seems like his modus operandi at work.

So is Andre now dead? Is he more dead than before? Is he still alive, but with some perspective after being forced to feel what he was doing to others? Is he trapped inside his own mind, reliving his worst experiences as he forced others to?